# Max common array slice in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of numbers and I need to find the maximum slice of the array which contains no more than two different numbers.

so if I have

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]
```

the output I'm looking is 10, because the array slice of (0, 9) is the largest slice of the array with no more than two different numbers.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: Look into array.map and array.filter on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: you can use RegExp for this, instead of lots of looping

Comment: You don't need to specify a "comma-delimited array". Arrays are arrays. They have no delimiters except in source code, and then they are *always* delimited by commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example does the trick for you. However I kindly ask other higher programming gods to improve this or provide another solution. I think this code could be greatly optimized. Please comment if you find bugs, or examples to which this function returns a faulty solution.

```
function returnLargestConsecutiveArraySlice(array)
{
    //set an empty array.
    var a = [];
    //walk the supplied array and check if number is not repeated
    array.filter(function (element, index, array) {
    if (element != array[index-1] && element != array[index+1])
    {
        a.push(index);
        return element;
    }
}
);

    //the returned array contains all indexes to the numbers that are not repeated.
    //walk the array and check if number the next number matches the current one.
    //If so the index is consecutive. 
    var numbers = a;
    var b = [[]]; //use an empty array to start with.
    var index = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length-1; i++){
        if(numbers[i+1] == numbers[i]+1)
        {
            //number is consecutive, add.
          b[index].push(numbers[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            //chain broken, start a new one.
            index++;
            b[index] = [];
        }
    }

    //we now have an array with all chains. Look for the largest chain.
    var largest = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
    {
        if (b[i].length > largest.length)
        {
            largest = b[i];
        }
    }
    //largest chain found. Slice the original array on the largest chain.
    return array.slice(largest[0], largest[0] + largest.length+1);
}

console.log(returnLargestConsecutiveArraySlice([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 1, 1, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 2, 2, 6, 2, 1, 8]));
```